# Responsive Twitter Widget in Zurb Foundation

Tags: twitter, zurb-foundation

Here's an issue that I'm having. I'll post screenshots because explaining it might not hit the point that I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: This is good!]

[image: This is bad!!!]

Essentially, when I resize my browser window, the entire Twitter feed becomes disproportionate from the panel's sizing format. I believe the fix is within the actual js file that Twitter provides, but I might be wrong, hence the reason I'm asking.

If any solutions are available, please point me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, with help from another post on Stackoverflow.

1) Modify the widgets.js file provided by twitter, use jsbeautifier to organize the code in a readable format.

2) Modify the following code:

```
I.prototype = new n, m.aug(I.prototype, {
            renderedClassNames: "twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered",
            dimensions: {
                DEFAULT_HEIGHT: "600",
                DEFAULT_WIDTH: "520",
                NARROW_WIDTH: "320",
                MIN_WIDTH: "100",
                MIN_HEIGHT: "200",
                WIDE_MEDIA_PADDING: 81,
                NARROW_MEDIA_PADDING: 16,
                WIDE_MEDIA_PADDING_CL: 60,
                NARROW_MEDIA_PADDING_CL: 12
            },
```

Changing the MIN_WIDTH: to 100 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization), the minimum width for the Twitter widget is 180px.  They've probably chosen to restrict the width to above this size to avoid shortening the line length too much and making the tweets hard to read.  I see two possible solutions for this:

- **Give the widget more horizontal space:** You can make the widget proportionally wider on small screens using a media query, or, if you're using Foundation 5, you can make its container wider on screens in that range using the medium grid.
- **Change the layout:** Does the timeline need to be in a sidebar like that? Would you be better off putting it underneath the textual content, displaying it horizontally, or not having it there at all (what is the value you're trying to provide the user by including it)?

Hopefully these suggestions help.  Sorry I don't have a direct technical fix for making the widget display smaller.